# the sum operation in a normed space is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $  (E, \parallel \parallel) $ is a normed space , then the function $ + : E \times E \rightarrow E $ , $ ( x , y) \mapsto x + y $ is continuous.

Question:
to solve this exercise ... Which it is the norm for space $(E \times E,  \parallel \parallel_{E\times E} )$?

Comment: Usually: $\|(x,y)\|_{E\times E}:=\|x\|_E+\|y\|_E$.

Comment: Why? ... Could you explain that to me? Please

Comment: With this definition .... exercise is very easy to solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For continuity to make sense here, it's not necessary to have a norm on $E \times E$; having a topology on $E \times E$ would suffice. The natural choice of topology on $E \times E$ would be the product topology. In this case, showing that $+: E\times E \to E$ is continuous at a point $(x,y)\in E\times E$ means to show that, for every open neighborhood $W$ of $x+y$, there exist neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ of $x$ and $y$ respectively such that $U+V \subseteq W$.

It is also true that the product topology on $E \times E$ is induced by the norm $\|(x,y)\| := \|x\| + \|y\|$, so that would be another way to approach it.

Comment: Thank you very much ... his response leaves me 100% satisfied.